# Firestore: Multiple whereArrayContains

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection called "service". And the services have two attributes called, serviceableAt (where the service is available) and accessibleBy (who can access it).

```
service-1
    serviceableAt
        0 - Location-1
        1 - Location-2
    accessibleBy
        0 - Seller
        1 - Customer
```

I am trying to fetch all the services who are serviceable at `Location-1` and accessible to `Seller`. So my query was:

```
fun services(at: String, by: UserRole) = firestore().collection(Refs.SERVICE_REF)
    .whereArrayContains(Fields.SERVICEABLE_AT, at)
    .whereArrayContains(Fields.ACCESSIBLE_BY, by)
```

Looks like multiple `whereArrayContains` are not supported. So what could be the alternate solution for temporarry basis until Firebase team comes up with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The common alternative would be to store the information as map fields:

```
servicableAtMap: {
  "Location-1": true,
  "Location-2": true
},
accessibleByMap: {
  "Seller": true,
  "Buyer": true
}
```

With the above you can now use equality conditions to find the matches, and you **can** have multiple equality filters in a query.

The downside of the above approach is that it will create/require a separate index for each sub-field, so that takes up [more storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63384221/firestore-indexes-pricing#:%7E:text=1%20Answer&text=The%20only%20cost%20for%20indexes,doc%20writes%2Fegress%20bandwidth) and contributes towards the [maximum number of indexes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#indexes) you can have.