# Does adding a Firestore index cause a read operation for every existing document?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

If I add a new Firestore index to a database that already contains 100 documents will I be charged 100 reads for the index operation? I'm assuming it needs to scan all or at least a portion of the existing docs in order to index them.

[This is a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63384221/firestore-indexes-pricing) but I can't tell if it's referring to the ongoing cost of an index rather than the creation of one.

Answer (score 1):

**No**. As Puff wrote very clearly:

> The only cost for indexes is their storage cost

You will only be charged for the storage of them.

Comment: Would love if we could disable indexing entirely in specified collections, 98% of the time, indexing is not needed