# Handling Multiple Optional Conditions in Firestore Queries - flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get documents from Firestore with conditions. There are 5 conditions where 4 of them are optional.  It depends on user input (the user can enter conditions. depending on the user.)

My problem is that I have to create indexes in Firestore. If I use 5 conditions all time, It's enough 1 index. But, In this situation, Some users use 4 conditions, and someone uses 2,3,1. I don't know how many. So, I have to create many indexes. (more than 20). What can I do about this?

*I have an idea for it.
All conditions work every time (1 index), But, If the user does not give value to that condition, That condition give all documents. So, I used this method to success my idea. But there is errors. help me to improve my idea or give me another idea to do this.*

Code for my idea:

- set a function to `Stream` of `StreamBuilder` Widget.
- That function's code below:

`profession`, `religion`, `status` etc. values get from user inputs.

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> getDataStream(
    String religion,
    String status,
    String profession,
    String foods,
    String education,
  ) {
    var query = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .where("ethanicity", isEqualTo: "Test");

    // religion
    if (religion != "") {
      query = query.where("religion", isEqualTo: religion);
    }
    if (religion == "") {
      query = query.where("religion", isNotEqualTo: "");
    }

    // Status
    if (status != "") {
      query = query.where("status", isEqualTo: status);
    }
    if (status == "") {
      query = query.where("status", isNotEqualTo: "");
    }

    // // profession
    if (profession != "") {
      query = query.where("profession", isEqualTo: profession);
    }
    if (profession == "") {
      query = query.where("profession", isNotEqualTo: "");
    }

    // // foods
    if (foods != "") {
      query = query.where("status", isEqualTo: foods);
    }
    if (foods == "") {
      query = query.where("status", isNotEqualTo: "");
    }

    //education
    if (education != "") {
      query = query.where("education", isEqualTo: education);
    } else {
      query = query.where("education", isNotEqualTo: "");
    }

    return query.snapshots();
  }
```

Problem :
I can use `isNotEqualTo` multiple times in a **single query**. Can't use like this.

Comment: You need to leave out the `where` condition for every field the user has not given input. And you will need composite indexes for every possible combination where more than one field is included, you can't avoid that with Firestore.

Comment: @PeterKoltai  If I do it like this, I can have a performance impact on my database, as each index incurs additional overhead for maintaining and updating the index.

Comment: Is there no way to do this without many indexes?

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to go without all the indexes. Firestore will give you an error on every query that can't find a proper index. With other databases like MySQL theoretically you can make queries without indexes but this is not recommended anyway.

Comment: Without indexes the only option for the database engine to serve you query is to perform a full table scan. That is very inefficient in most of the cases so Firebase won't let you do that.

Comment: Got it. Thank you. If i created more than 30 indexes, It will be a problem?

Comment: You are welcome. From performance point of view it should not give you headache unless you have a really huge database. As for the costs, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63384221/firestore-indexes-pricing).

Comment: Ok. Have any method to create all indexes automatically? manually doing spends a long time.

Comment: You can edit Firestore indexes in a local `firestore.indexes.json` file and use cli with command `firebase deply --only firestore` to deploy the indexes to Firestore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251837/discussion-between-horiz-and-peter-koltai).

Answer (score 1):

I know two ways to do this, the scalable and the not so scalable version.

Scalable: Use Algolia plugin as an external service to search, it's worth the time learning as you will have a bunch of power for queries.

The other solution is as per https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#limitations firebase limitation, you can only filter on the same field.

You could create an array field called filters `["status", "religion"]` and from there you can use a where in query. Now, this is hard to escalate as you would have to update such an array every time a property changes.